Matrix representation of $\partial_k$ in the paper "Computing persistent homology"
I am a postgraduate student majoring in applied mathematics, and recently I try to learn how to construct persistent homology in an algebraic way. But I am now struggling with the well-known 2005 paper Computing Persistent Homology by A. Zomorodian and G. Carlsson. I want to understand its underlying algebra, but feel extremely difficult with only a basic knowledge on abstract algebra (almost ignorant on commutative or homological algebra).
Put aside the detailed proofs of all "big" algebraic theorem, I managed to sort out a pathway for calculating a persistent homology given a filtration of a simplicial complex.
My question comes in Section 4.1. The authors gave a toy example of a filtration as Fig. 1:

and they derived a matrix representation for $\partial_1$, the first boundary operator:

here Table 1 is as follows:

What I have known is that a persistent module on a field $F$ is equivalent to a graded module over $F[t]$, and the latter is a very complex algebra structure with every element as "a series of cycle cosets series" formed by two times of direct sums.
My questions are:

How this matrix representation (Eq. (7)) associates with all the complicated algebras in Section 2 and 3?
The matrix representation of boundary operators is simple and intuitive. But Eq. (7) is apparently not the common representation.
What does the "degrees of the simplices" even mean? In Table 1, it seems that authors simply regard it as the filtration index that some simplex firstly enter the filtration. But the degree of elements on graded module is proposed earlier in this paper, and by no way "simplices" can be regarded as the element of the persistence module!

If anyone can give any help, I will appreciate it.

You may find this YouTube video helpful: https://youtu.be/qGkIuJmXhts?si=RZYDEHqMAOngXIOm

@HenryAdams Thank you! This video is helpful!
